# event.target is not working on mobile

Tags: javascript, forms, meteor

I am using a form to collect data. Once the user hits submit, it is suppose to update the user and question documents. The function works on desktop but not on mobile.

When I hard code the values `answer` and `wager` it works on both. The issue seems to be `event.target.wager.value`. I tried putting the values in a `Session` and I tried converting them to int and strings.

Code below is on `Main.js`

```
Template.questionCard.events({
    'submit form': function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var questionId = this._id;
        var currentUser = Meteor.userId();

        // Collects the data from the form when submitted.
        // var answer = event.target.play.value;
        // var wager = event.target.wager.value;

    var answer = "Run";
    var wager = 5000;

    //Add user data to question
    Meteor.call('questionAnswered', currentUser, questionId, answer, wager);

    console.log('User: ' + currentUser + ' answered question ' + questionId + ' -- ' + answer + ' ' + wager);
}
```

Below is the `questionAnswered` method called.

```
'questionAnswered' : function( user, questionId, answer, wager){
    QuestionList.update(questionId, {$push: {usersAnswered: user}});
    console.log(user + " answered " + questionId)
    console.log("User wagered " + wager + " coins." );
    Meteor.users.update( {_id: user}, {$inc: { "profile.coins": -wager}} );


    //Add question, wager and answer to the user's account.
    Meteor.users.update( { _id: user}, {$push: {questionAnswered: { questionId: questionId, 
        wager: wager, answered: answer}}});
    console.log(user + " answered " + answer);

    //Update the question with the users answer and wager.
    if (answer == "Run"){
        QuestionList.update(questionId, {$push: { usersRun: {userID: user, amount: wager } }});
    } else if (answer == "Pass"){
        QuestionList.update(questionId, {$push: {usersPass: {userID: user, amount: wager}}});
    } else if (answer == "Fumble"){
        QuestionList.update(questionId, {$push: {usersFumble: {userID: user, amount: wager}}});
    } else if (answer == "Interception"){
        QuestionList.update(questionId, {$push: {usersInterception: {userID: user, amount: wager}}});
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a comment by Jimmy Mian-Guan Lim [here](https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/a-look-at-a-meteor-template/). Using the radio input and the name of the group to find the checked option. Then returning the value.

```
    var answer = template.find('input:radio[name=play]:checked').value;
    var wager = template.find('input:radio[name=wager]:checked').value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `event.currentTarget` instead.

Meteor seems to work a bit better with it.